Hover child inside parent and affect other child inside other parent too (sibling parent)
I have question about hovering sibling other child, here is my code:
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
</div>


I try this style code, is working, but i found some problem
.parent:has(.child:hover) ~ .parent .child {
  background-color: red;
}

The problem is, when the 1st child is hovered, all the other child (the 2nd and 3rd) is hovered too, but when I hover the 2nd child, only the 3rd is hovered, the 1st child is not affected... Can you please help me solving the problem, thank you.

can you let us know what you want to achieve exactly?
